# How to enable my app to be called to complete an action

Tags: android, android-browser

I am currently developing an android web browser and i would like my application to be called or to be set as the default web browser, Just like when you have Opera and Chrome and when you try to open a link it asks you to chose one application and with two options, Always and Just Once.
Thank you

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional IntentFilter for a browser:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest, add category: Browsable and Default to the activity intentfilter. This will define you application as a browser application.

```
<intent-filter> 
...
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
</intent-filter>
```